# oData request with query paramater as URL

Tags: odata

Is there a way to retrieve the published content from broker DB by passing the page url as one of the query string parameter?

Lets say i have a published page with path "http://host:port/AAA/index.jsp"

can i pass the "uri=/AAA/index.jsp" as a parameter to odata request? 
Though I dont see url as one of the defined type, just wanted to see is there any workaround for this.

Answer (score 2):

I think by '**defined types**' you mean the `Collections` available to query in the odata service. These are called "**Entities**" in the OData protocol, but in these collections, what we have are units of information (`Items`) inside the Broker Database to be queried.

If you are trying to obtain a certain `Page`, using the url in the request to the odata service, the solution may be the use one of the "**Query options**" in the OData standard, for example the "`$filter`" element in the odata request, something like the following url, gives a result of the Page published with a certain url:

```
http://your_server:port/odata_webservice/odata.svc/Pages?$filter=(Url%20eq%20%27/AAA/index.jsp%27)
```

And if you want to access the published content in that Page, then you can use another "query option" of OData protocol like "`$expand`"

```
http://your_server:port/odata_webservice/odata.svc/Pages?$filter=(Url%20eq%20%27/AAA/index.jsp%27)&$expand=PageConent
```

or

```
http://your_server:port/odata_webservice/odata.svc/Pages?$filter=(Url%20eq%20%27/AAA/index.jsp%27)&$expand=ComponentPresentations
```

---

It's important to note that the OData service implemented in Tridion is a partial implementation of the OData Protocol.

Information about the capabilities of OData service in Tridion can be followed with this [link](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-2F41CB23-912F-4149-9C16-34AB00E67E4E).

And information about the OData capabilities can be followed [here](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/).